# Android: proper usage of RelativeLayout

Tags: android-layout

I will try to represent the desired layout using text:

Stock Name

==========

symbol | score

GOOG   | 76

**symbol** and **GOOG** should be in a single vertical Linear layout to group them and they should be aligned to the left **score** and **76** should also be in a a single vertical Linear layout to group them but they should be aligned to the right.

This is my layout. I could achieve it by the way you can see below. Does anyone got an idea what I am doing wrong? (this is only the relevant portion of the layout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/stock_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="40dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/stock_symbol" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/stock_symbol"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="30dp" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/stock_score" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/stock_score"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="30dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I also tried using `android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/relative_layout"` and `android:layout_alignRight="@+id/relative_layout"` inside the `LinearLayout` but without success.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error thanks to @RobinHood from the chat room "Android-People":

I had to replace the inner LinearLayouts with RelativeLayout and the inner RelariveLayout should change from android:layout_width="fill_parent" to android:layout_width="wrap_content"

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/stock_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="40dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout        
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"            
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/stock_symbol" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/stock_symbol"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="30dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/stock_score" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/stock_score"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="30dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```